# Can we set the root without password?

Tags: ssh, password, security, root

Suppose that I had set the root password before with `ssh` key. Hereinafter, I want to let the root without password. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This may be of some help to you. I'm not familiar with doing what you want, so I can't support you further. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: What do you mean?  Did you set a password on the root account, or install your ssh key into /root/.ssh/authorized_keys?

Comment: @Dash_plus_Java : Thank you for the reference, I will read it and try to understand.

Comment: @psusi , sorry for not being precise, but I mean when we set root password on the root account. When we leave the password blank, is that mean that we have no root password? BTW, I am also interested about installing `ssh` key into `/root` . Would you mind to give me a little explanation on that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu the root account has no password but is locked by default, so that you can not log in as root using a password.  If you paste your public key ( `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` ) into root's authorized_keys file ( `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` ) then you can log in via 'ssh' as root without needing a password.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set the root without password to [SSH login without password](http://namhuy.net/2433/ssh-login-without-password.html), but it's highly not recommended, user other user then use su to become root.